# Birthday List sorting according to date form

Tags: excel

I Have Master Data in Sheet "Bday" I want to display the birthday in sorting as I enter it in Bday sheet... it should be sorted in another sheet "current bday" according to date.(auto)

I have tried in Difference sheet by using Vlookup but it is not sorted as per date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If master sheet is your Sheet1 and birthdays are in column A, paste the below formula in Sheet2 (sorted sheet),

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(Sheet1!A:A,ROW()),"")
```

and drag it throughout the complete column, or assign the formula for the complete column by selcting the column name and pasting the formula in formula bar and hitting `ctrl`+`enter`.

Whenever you add a bday in master sheet, it will automatically populate in sheet2 in sorted order. You may have to adjust the formula if you are not starting from row 1.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, its works but not what i need, if i change the row number e.g sheet1!A1:A22 the date is different & again when i increase number of row that is Sheet1!A1:A500 the date shows again different date.

Comment: Just use A:A and it would work. If not post the error that you get

Comment: @shiva, Thanks, let me give more details of my data
i have Column A Sr No, Column B Date (birth) column c Name & Column d is years. this all date is in sheet called "bday" I have data of 1500 rows the B column is asorted data 
I want all this data in another sheet by auto sorted the B column, and that too happen as I enter new row in sheet "bday" in new sheet it should be auto sorted as per date

Comment: I got it. Just use the formula inside an index match and get all data that is required. You can google it if you are not sure about index match formulas